# SVG misaligned when resizing screen

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm using some SVG's above and below a div to create an interesting shape that also scales well on small screens. A reduced test case can be seen here:

https://codepen.io/jciw/pen/eYWEazp

The SVG seems to align perfectly sometimes, but when resizing you can see a small (1px) gap between the SVG and the above or below div (to the left and the right). I'm assuming this is a rounding error, but is it solvable?

Reduced test case code:

```
    <div class="container">
        <svg class="homepage-rect-top" width="566" height="55" viewBox="0 0 566 55" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M9.81142 16.8646L554.811 54.484C560.592 54.883 565.5 50.3017 565.5 44.5078V0.5H0.5V6.88831C0.5 12.1439 4.5683 16.5026 9.81142 16.8646Z" fill="white"/>
        </svg>
        <div class="homepage-rectangle">

        </div>
        <svg class="homepage-rect-bottom" width="566" height="55" viewBox="0 0 566 55" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M9.81142 16.8646L554.811 54.484C560.592 54.883 565.5 50.3017 565.5 44.5078V0.5H0.5V6.88831C0.5 12.1439 4.5683 16.5026 9.81142 16.8646Z" fill="white"/>
        </svg>
    </div>



 body {
      background: #999999;
    }
    
    .container {
      max-width: 80%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .homepage-rectangle {
        background: white;
        min-height: 300px;
    }
    
    .homepage-rect-bottom {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        display: block;
        stroke: white;
    }
    
    .homepage-rect-top {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        display: block;
        stroke: white;
        transform: scaleY(-1);
        margin-bottom: -5px;
    }
    
    .reverse-it {
        transform: scaleX(-1);
    }
    
    .flip-reverse-it {
        transform: scale(-1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be what I think was a rounding issue when using transforms on the SVG's. When using non-transformed SVG's this wasn't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you simply put this in .homepage-rect-bottom:

```
margin-top:-1px;
```

in .homepage-rect-top use

```
margin-bottom: -1px
```

Comment: It's the left and right alignment that's the issue - apologies, I should of made this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see, ok, well I wouldn't go for an svg in that case, I would play around with something of the likes of this, which you can play around with:

```
body {
  background: #999999;
}

.container{
  max-width: 80%;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.panel--one {
  width:100%;
  height: 450px;
  background: white;
  transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(-15deg);
  border-radius:2rem;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel--one"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a pretty cool solution. Unfortunately, in my case I need the content of this not transformed in any way, with a flexible auto height.